# Wrongly differentiating the childs' actions in an Expandable list view

Tags: android, android-intent, switch-statement, parent-child, expandablelistview

I have a simple **Expandable List View** in a **Fragment** with only two levels of lists: **parent** and **child**.

I would like to deploy methods when clicking on the **child**, so that each **child** opens up a different activities.

Now, I am using a **setOnChildClickListener** on my "expListView" this way

```
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View view,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent Open00 = new Intent(getActivity(), First.class);
                            getActivity().startActivityForResult(Open00, 0);
                            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bounce, R.anim.bounce);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent Open01 = new Intent(getActivity(), Second.class);
                            getActivity().startActivityForResult(Open01, 0);
                            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bounce, R.anim.bounce);
                            break;
                    }

                case 1:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent Open1 = new Intent(getActivity(), Popup1.class);
                            getActivity().startActivityForResult(Open1, 1);
                            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bounce, R.anim.bounce);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent Open2 = new Intent(getActivity(), Popup2.class);
                            getActivity().startActivityForResult(Open2, 1);
                            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bounce, R.anim.bounce);
                            break;
                    }
                case 2:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 2:

                            break;
                        case 3:

                            break;
                    }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

What happens now, is that if I click on the **first** child (number **0**) of the **first** group (number **0** again), it opens two activities, i.e. the number **0** from the group **0** and the **0**th from the group **1**.

I am wondering why, given that I have also used the switches to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I found it, jeez!

```
        expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                    int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            switch (groupPosition) {
                case 0:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent Open00 = new Intent(getActivity(), First.class);
                            getActivity().startActivityForResult(Open00, 0);
                            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bounce, R.anim.bounce);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent Open01 = new Intent(getActivity(), Second.class);
                            getActivity().startActivityForResult(Open01, 0);
                            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bounce, R.anim.bounce);
                            break;
                    }
                    **break**;

                case 1:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:
                            Intent Open1 = new Intent(getActivity(), Popup1.class);
                            getActivity().startActivityForResult(Open1, 1);
                            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bounce, R.anim.bounce);
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            Intent Open2 = new Intent(getActivity(), Popup2.class);
                            getActivity().startActivityForResult(Open2, 1);
                            getActivity().overridePendingTransition(R.anim.bounce, R.anim.bounce);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case 2:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 2:

                            break;
                        case 3:

                            break;
                    }
                    **break**;
                case 3:
                    switch (childPosition) {
                        case 0:

                            break;
                        case 1:

                            break;
                    }
                    **break**;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I forgot to enter the break at the end of the groupcase!